# Converting Ubuntu Unity to Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

I'd like to switch to Ubuntu Gnome from Ubuntu 16.10 but haven't found any working [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Installation#Cross-grading_from_Ubuntu_To_Ubuntu_GNOME). The answers on askubuntu are outdated as well.

I went with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop^

sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove unity
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-settings
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove 'unity*'
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove 'libunity*'

# thanks @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy:
sudo apt-get remove compiz jayatana

# reinstalls the parts of Unity required by Ubuntu Gnome
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop^
```

Is there anything I missed that can be uninstalled? Like packages that are installed by Ubuntu but that are not present in Ubuntu Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same, but I'm thinking of just waiting for 17.04 and nuke & pave. I've been using Gnome on another test computer to get back to basics of Gnome prior to switching back. These other methods are OK except I'm concerned with leaving unnecessary crap laying about. Just my thoughts.

Comment: 17.04 still uses Unity ... you would need to wait for 17.10

Comment: AFAIK 17.10 will still Use Unity. You need to wait for 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

There are some applications that rely on unity in order to work. So even if you remove unity, some parts of it will be reinstalled in order for those applications to work. For instance, if you want to use Gnome flashback, then it uses parts of unity, so not every part of unity would be removed. You should install GDM which is the display manager for Gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

During the installation you will be presented with a screen to select between lightdm and gdm as your default gdm, choose gdm and then you can uninstall lightdm.

Comment: I know that some parts of unity will be reinstalled - that's OK. With 'anything I missed' I meant if there are packages that are included with ubuntu that are not part of ubuntu gnome. I updated my question.

Comment: compiz and ayatana should be gone, for one, but these are specific features of Unity, which for average user aren't crucial. app indicator support also will be gone but that is fixable with extensions for gnome

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 is last version where GNOME Flashback use Unity parts.

Comment: `gdm` is already a dependency of `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` which OP installed according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using gnome on ubuntu 16.10.Only place you need to decide is the display manager.lightdm or gdm. Use synaptic to see all pacakages related to unity if you want to remove. You can see other program dependancy also then.